# Spring boot not displaying first view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a spring boot application. My problem is that when I run the project, my login page is not shown. This is my code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RestLogin {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

I get only a white page and "login" is written in it. When I try to change the `@RestController` with `@Controller` I get this `GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 ()`. My login.html page is located under the webapp>tpl>login.html

How can I display my login page?

**Edit**

This is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleApplication.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ExampleApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you working with JSPs?

Comment: @Paner I'm working with angular and html

Answer (score 2):

I dont know your configuration but:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                                         .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

In the Application.properties file add:

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .html
```

Change `@RestController` to `@Controller` for RestLogin class. Also put your html file inside the static folder inside resources folder.

Comment: I tried to create a test.html in the resources>static folder, then I in the RestLogin class I did return "test" but I'm getting the same problem

Comment: When I change RestController annotation to Controller I got this GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 ()

Comment: you have to add the server context if you dont know it add server.contextPath=/server to your Application.properties file and then when you run it you should go to localhost:8080/server

Comment: Should the server.contextPath value be the same as what I have to put in the @RequestMapping ?

Comment: No, it is for the url.

Comment: Excuse me if it's a stupid question: when the application run for the first time, it goes by default to the "/" url? What's the rule of the server.contextPath?

Comment: Yes, i think you should start reading before implementing. You can start from here https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

You need an application class with a main method. See [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

Here's a snippet:

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: @Llg can you please share all of your code? It is hard to help you using only what you have provided.

Comment: @Llg it appears as though Spring is unable to find your login.html file. Where is it located in your project structure?

Comment: It's under two folders in the webapp folder

Comment: @Llg apologies, I see you have that in your post. You should create a resources directory and place login.html in `/resources/templates/`

Comment: Is spring boot only detecting files in the /ressouces/templates/ ? Is it impossible to keep them in the webapp? Excuse me I'm new to spring boot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141842/discussion-between-jmhage-and-llg).

Comment: Can you please check the discussion?

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior.

New version of Spring web comes with @RestController annotation which nothing but `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`. So when you have a return statement in a method you must use `@RestController` or annotate your method with `@ResponseBody`.

Here the problem is that Spring don't know a lot about the http method type, can you please try to use `@GetMapping("/")` to combinbe path and method at the same time.

Comment: It's recommanded to have web files under src/main/resources/templates/

Answer (score 0):

**According to your posted code and your description, you're getting an expected behavior.**

When you annotate your controller with `@RestController`, that means that your methods on that controller will try to return their result as JSON.

According to your code:

```
@RestController
public class RestLogin {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

You're returning the String "login", that's why you're getting empty white page with the word login **as JSON**

If you will change the `@RestController` to `@Controller` then it no longer will return your string as JSON,

but Spring will try to figure out from the that "login" string a view, **and for that you'll need to add a view resolver bean to your project.**